# Telethon send messages in list in asynchronous manner

Tags: loops, asynchronous, python-asyncio, telethon

Sorry for any broken english...

So, basically, I have a list containing messages and their destinies:

```
messages = [(id_1, msg_1), (id_2, msg_2), (id_3, msg_3),]
```

What I want is to use a: `async for msg in messages` however, my list, obviously, isn't asynchronously iterable (I am using sqlite3) how can I convert it to a asynchronously iterable list?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need "asynchronously iterable lists". You can just iterate normally:

```py
for (id, msg) in messages:
    # do things...
```

If you *really* need an "async iterable list", you can wrap it like so, however note this is probably very unnecessary (and it also requires a recent Python version):

```py
async def make_async_iter(lst):
    for item in lst:
        yield item

...

async for item in make_async_list(messages):
    # use item...
```

Comment: 1 - Thanks! 2 - I am using an: `@client.on(events.NewMessage)` so I can send and receive messages at the same time, but I am trying to make them not block each other so the whole thing dont stop working. 3 - I think I will give a better look at the examples.

Comment: By default, a new `asyncio` task is spawned for each update, so they don't wont block each other. Only problem occurs if you use blocking methods (like `time.sleep` instead of `asyncio.sleep`).

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much! I ended up solving the problem as you suggested earlier, but this still usefull!